# When mp4 is uploaded it doesn't appear in the $_FILES/$_POST array

Tags: php, file-upload, iis-7

I have the following html to upload files:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
?>

<form method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Selecteer een bestand:*
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: hand;" type="submit" name="insturen" value="Insturen">
                <input style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: hand;" type="submit" name="klaar" value="Klaar met Uploaden">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

There is no problem when the file is like 190KB. But when the files get bigger (for example 20MB) the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays will be totally empty.

One of the solutions i found was changing the php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 3000
memory_limit = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

This did not help, so i thought let's try to change the .htaccess file:

```
#set php upload values
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
php_value post_max_size 1024M
php_value max_execution_time 3000
```

This didn't do the job either. As this server runs on IIS 7.5 I have already set the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` to the correct values.

If anyone knows something that might lead me closer to my goal of uploading up to 900MB video files, please do tell. Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: .htaccess on IIS? Anyway, what does `ini_get` return (for the config values you changed)? Is your php.ini in the right place?

Comment: `my goal of uploading up to 900MB video files` - this sounds like a job for a Java/Flash etc applet which does it in chunks to me, rather than just using the standard HTTP uploads provided by PHP/web servers - you would want some kind of resume functionality for files of that size, which is (AFAIK) impossible to implement using a web page alone. These can also provide nice features like drap and drop. There are plenty of free out-of-the-box solutions, like [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/)...

Comment: @Jonny Keogh I changed it in the windows/php.ini file and in the plesk/php/php.ini file, but it turns out that plesk found it funny to use plesk/php5/php.ini. found this by using `ini_get("extension_dir")`. THANKS!!

@DaveRandom i dont want to use javascript/flash on this website. But it seems the problem is solved now :)

Comment: @Jonny Keogh .htaccess on IIS works thru Hellicon APE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that plesk changed from `plesk/php/php.ini` to `plesk/php5/php.ini` while not deleting the first one. after changing the second file all was fine.

I found this by using `ini_get("extension_dir")` which will tell you the location of the extensions, and in my case also which php folder it was using!

thanks to Jonny Keogh for leading me in this direction (in the comments of this question)!